# Convert SQL statement to PyMongo

Tags: sql, pymongo, aggregate-functions

I have the following SQL query which I am trying to convert to PyMongo

```
SELECT sum(pop), city
FROM mongo.test.zips
WHERE state = ‘CO’ and pop > 1000
GROUP BY city
ORDER BY sum(pop) DESC
```

I am struggling with the ORDER BY statement and would appreciate any help on how to implement this in PyMongo. I have experimented with the aggregate function but can't reproduce the SQL.

This is what I have so far :

```
import pymongo
myclient = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost:27017/")
mydb = myclient["test"]
mycol = mydb["zips"]
myquery = { "state": "CO" , "pop" : { "$gt" : 1000 }}
mydoc = mycol.find(myquery).sort("pop", -1)
for x in mydoc:
  print(x)
```

Thanks for any help !

Comment: What do your documents look like?  Are there multiple documents with the same `city`?  Perhaps this is a collection of neighborhoods or ZIP Codes?

Comment: I have a single document with data in the following form {
  "_id": "10280",
  "city": "NEW YORK",
  "state": "NY",
  "pop": 5574,
  "loc": [
    -74.016323,
    40.710537
  ]
}https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/aggregation-zip-code-data-set/

Comment: It's very strange to only have one document with aggregation steps like `sum`, `group`, and `order`.  Without more than one document, there's really no point.